# How to use a code with arrays and strings?

Tags: c, arrays, string

Here are the instructions I was given:

1. If the command word is `find`, read an additional integer and search the data set for that integer.
2. If the command word is `print`, print the array
3. Any other command word is an error.
4. No command word will be longer than 20 characters.
5. After reading the `n+1` values, there will be one more integer (k) read from the keyboard.
6. Search the array for the value k. If found, print the location where k was found. (1 = data value, n = last data value).
7. If `k` is not found, print `not found`. This is not an error.
8. If there are more than one value `k` in the data, only print the location of the first one.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
   int n;
   scanf ("%d", &n);
   if (n < 1) {
      printf ("Error: one or more values must be provided.\n");
      return 1;
   }

   int x [n];
   int a;
   a = 0;
   while (a < n) {
      scanf ("%d", x [a]);
      a = a + 1;
   }

   int k;
   scanf ("%d", &k);
   int i;
   i = 0;
   while (i <= n-1) {
      if (x[i] == k) {
         break;
      }
      i = i + 1;
   }
   if (i < n) {
      printf ("%d\n", k+1);
   } else {
      printf ("not found\n");
   }

   printf ("Error: invalid command\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Suggested Strategy:

1. After reading the array data, read a string.
2. If the string is `find`, read integer `k` and perform a search.
3. If the string is `print`, do not read `k`, just print the data in the array.
4. If the string is not `find` or `print`, handle the error.

Comment: Expected Output: 3 2 0 4 print.... 2 0 4------ 3 2 0 4 nothing... Error: invalid command----------- 3 2 0 4 find 2.......1------ 3 2 0 4 find 9...... not found

Comment: You should've paid more attention to the step-by-step instructions when getting ready to ask your first question... It's not clear what you want, and it just seems to be asking for the solution to a homework assignment.

Comment: Suggested Strategy: 1. after reading the array, read a string. 2. if the string is find, read integer k and perform a search. 3. if the string is print, do not read k, print the data in the array. 4. if the string is not find or print, handle the error.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Your profile says you're a Psychology major... but they're making you write code in ***C*** of all languages?... Can you try a more forgiving language like Python? It might save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: I'm asking  for a explanation for what the instructions are asking and this code is for an elective.

Comment: I've fixed some typos and made some of the formatting easier to read. Please correct if I misunderstood anything. Regarding the instructions, I'm not sure what's unclear to you. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Also, the `int x [n];` line won't work because `n` is a variable not known at compile time. You'll need to use `int *x = malloc(n * sizeof int);` and then `free(x);` when you no longer need to use your `x` array.

Comment: @codedredd `int x [n];` is a [*variable length array*](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-length-arrays-in-c-and-c/) whose length is determined at run time.

Comment: @WeatherVane I actually had to write code here to test that out because, in the link you posted, the examples have constant literals in place and do not ask for user input at runtime, leading me to think that the array size would've been inferred at _compile_ time instead. I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Shai'Tavia, I hope my answer will help you see how you may make your code work. You've got the first part down, but you will need to compare the command string given by the user to then make a decision on what to do next.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRAYLENGTH 8

void printArray(int *array, int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void search(int *array, int key)
{
    int flag = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYLENGTH; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == key && flag == 0)
        {
            printf("found %d at index: %d\n", key, i);
            flag = 1;
        }
    }

    if (flag == 0)
        printf("not found\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    char command[20];
    int indx = 0;
    int array[] = {1, 4, 6, 8, 43, 61, 34, 2};
    int n, flag = 0;

    printf("How many times will we run?");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n < 1)
    {
        printf("Error: one or more values must be provided.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    do
    {
        printf("Enter the command word:");
        scanf("%s", command);

        if (strcmp(command, "find") == 0)
        {
            scanf("%d", &n);
            search(array, n);
        }

        else if (strcmp(command, "print") == 0)
            printArray(array, ARRAYLENGTH);

        else
            printf("Command not found\n");

    } while (--n > 0);

    printf("What is your final interger?");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    search(array, n);

    return 0;
}
```